# ACF to a woocommerce archive product page

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to add ACF to a woocommerce archive product page.

the_field('archive_product_footer', $term);

I understand that if I want to set a specific category page id do:

the_field('archive_product_footer', 'lawnmower_61');

But I'd like to make this a global ACF field I can access on every product category page.

If anyone could help me understand this it would be amazing.

Many thanks,
Elliott

Comment: in ACF you can set rule like if POST_Type is equal to Product than it will show on every product pages. i have done it

Comment: Add the ACF field group to the category itself.